# The Ladder Operators of Generalized Laguerre Polynomials

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, coordinate-systems, schroedinger-equation

I have the following wave function in cylindrical coordinates,

$$\psi(q,\phi) = \frac{1}{\pi^(3/4)}\sqrt{\frac{n!}{(n+m)!}}q^me^\frac{-q^2}{2}L^m_n(q^2) $$

where $q$ is the nondimensionalized radial component and $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle.

So, this is the nondimensionalized wave function associated to Quantum Harmonic Oscillator. My questions are:

1- Assuming photons exhibit Harmonic Oscillator like behavior, would this wave function coincide with the Energy Eigenstates of possible modes of propagation? (I mean can we describe their behavior via this wave function?)

2- What would be the Annihilation and Creation operators of this wave function? And what is the easiest way to find them? I think they must be way different than the standard one-dimensional Ladder operators $â$ and $â^+$.

Comment: *Assuming photons exhibit Harmonic Oscillator like behavior.* Photons always have speed $c$, while the speed of a harmonic oscillator oscillates and is sometimes zero. So your assumption is invalid. In QED, it is modes of the electromagnetic field that act like quantum harmonic oscillators.

Comment: *where $q$ is the nondimensionalized radial component and $\varphi$ is the azimuthal angle* Isn’t $\varphi$ supposed to appear on the right side?

Comment: \pi^(3/4) should be \pi^{3/4}

Comment: Sorry, but I mean exactly the same thing by saying "photons" as they are the Quantum counterpart of electromagnetism. 

Yes, but if you would know what the cylindrical transformed version of the Harmonic Oscillator wavefunction, you immediately recognize that it is simply $e^{jm\phi}$ which I do not have to indicate...

I did not get the reason of your last comment LOL!

Comment: *I did not get the reason of your last comment LOL!* Look at how the prefactor in front of the square root is incorrectly displayed. You have a simple MathJax/TeX error.

Answer (score 0):

Some spherical coordinate "ladder opertors" can be found from the following:

Let
$$
D_l = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}-\frac{  l}{r} +\omega r\right)=r^{+l} e^{-\omega r^2/2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} e^{+\omega r^2}r^{-l}\nonumber\\
D_l^\dagger = -\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{l+1}{r} -\omega r\right)= -r^{-(l+1)} e^{+\omega r^2/2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}e^{-\omega r^2/2} r^{(l+1)},\nonumber
$$
the "$\dagger$" being the adjoint with respect to the 2d inner product
$$
\langle f|g\rangle= \int_0^\infty f^*(r)g(r)\, r dr.
$$

We have that
$$
D_l^\dagger D_l = H_l -2(l+1) \omega\nonumber\\
D_l D_l^\dagger = H_{l+1} - 2l\omega\nonumber
$$
where
$$
H_l = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}- \frac 1 r \frac{\partial}{\partial r}+ \frac{l^2}{r^2}+ \omega^2r^2
$$
is the 2-d harmonic oscillator with eigenvalues
$$
E_{n,l}= 2\omega(2n+|l|+1),
$$
and normalized eigenfunctions
$$
\varphi_{n,l}(r,\phi) =|\omega|^{(|l|+1)/2} \sqrt{\frac{n!}{(n+|l|)!}} r^{|l|}\exp\left(-\frac{\omega r^2}{2}\right) L^{|l|}_n\left(\omega r^2\right) e^{il\theta}.
$$
Here
$$
L^{|l|}_n\left( r^2\right)= r^{-2|l|} e^{r^2}\frac 1{2r} \partial^n_r e^{-r^2} r^{2(n+|l|)}
$$
There are other such opertors.